# Python CGI - UTF-8 doesn't work

Tags: python, html, utf-8, python-3.x, cgi

For HTML5 and Python CGI:

If I write UTF-8 Meta Tag, my code doesn't work. 
If I don't write, it works.

Page encoding is UTF-8.

```
print("Content-type:text/html")
print()
print("""
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        şöğıçü
    </body>
    </html>
""")
```

This codes doesn't work.

```
print("Content-type:text/html")
    print()
    print("""
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            şöğıçü
        </body>
        </html>
    """)
```

But this codes works.

Comment: Did you specify a source encoding? What encoding was your file saved in by your editor? Python sends the string you typed *literally* so if you saved this file in Latin-1 encoding, that's what will be sent.

Comment: File encoding :utf-8. Normaly, it works. My previous projects worked it. I use Python3.3. Its default encoding is utf8.

by the way, i can't speak english. I don't understand sometimes

Comment: Aha, that's important information! You need to explicitly encode in that case, really.

Comment: if you will tell me where is problem, I can.
Server, browser, editor, html, etc ?

Comment: Voting to re-open this. Python 3 CGI printing is a *common pain point*, and far from a localised problem.

Comment: Seconded. Problems often occur if the webserver does not specify a locale to use for Python 3, and Python 3 assumes C and ASCII or legacy charset; and if the locale is not an UTF-8 locale...

Answer (score 10):

For CGI, using `print()` requires that the correct codec has been set up for output. `print()` writes to [`sys.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) and `sys.stdout` has been opened with a specific encoding and how that is determined is platform dependent *and* can differ based on how the script is run. Running your script as a CGI script means you pretty much do not know what encoding will be used.

In your case, the web server has set the locale for text output to a fixed encoding other than UTF-8. Python uses that locale setting to produce output in in that encoding, and without the `<meta>` header your browser correctly guesses that encoding (or the server has communicated it in the Content-Type header), but with the `<meta>` header you are telling it to use a different encoding, one that is incorrect for the data produced.

You can write directly to `sys.stdout.buffer`, after explicitly encoding to UTF-8. Make a helper function to make this easier:

```
import sys

def enc_print(string='', encoding='utf8'):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(string.encode(encoding) + b'\n')

enc_print("Content-type:text/html")
enc_print()
enc_print("""
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        şöğıçü
    </body>
    </html>
""")
```

Another approach is to replace `sys.stdout` with a new [`io.TextIOWrapper()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) that uses the codec you need:

```
import sys
import io

def set_output_encoding(codec, errors='strict'):
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(
        sys.stdout.detach(), errors=errors,
        line_buffering=sys.stdout.line_buffering)

set_output_encoding('utf8')

print("Content-type:text/html")
print()
print("""
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        şöğıçü
    </body>
    </html>
""")
```

Comment: This is really nice, but from what I see in the doc, this could also be implementation dependant! `This is not part of the TextIOBase API and may not exist in some implementations` (from http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html )

Comment: @Zenon: that may apply to certain implementations indeed (specifically `StringIO`), but the `stdout` stream definitely has a `.buffer` attribute; that is documented I the [`sys.stdout` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout).

Comment: not work in python3.4 , `Internal Server Error` happened

Comment: @alireza.m: the code, as posted here, works just fine on Python 3.4; I retested it just now. You have a different problem I'm afraid. Use `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()` (see the [module documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html)) to get more meaningful errors.

Comment: worked perfectly !! Thanks. Solved big problem of my code ! Thanks alot. is this the right way ? or use print() ?

Comment: @alireza.m this is the correct way; `print()` can easily fail if the CGI server doesn't provide a correct encoding for Python (it never does).

Answer (score 10):

From https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/352838/11350

First dont forget to set encoding in file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Then try

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

Or if you use apache2, add to your conf.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8    
SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8
```

Comment: Works when all else doesn't. But is it not absurd that we have to go this kind of arcane nonsense to do something so basic?

Comment: Thank you for what seems like the simplest and best answer.  Converting a CGI script from Python 2 to Python 3 is such a hassle!