# python utf-8 doesn't work, cgi

Tags: python, utf-8, cgi

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json,random,sys,io

PATH = "/srv/rudailynews/words.json"


print ("Content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n")

wordsfile=open(PATH,'r')
words=json.loads(wordsfile.read())
print(random.choice(words['subject'])+" "+
      random.choice(words['predicate'])+" "+
      random.choice(words['word3']))
```

This program should choose 3 random phrases from json and combine them. It runs from pycharm and from console normally but when i run it from a browser as a CGI i have an error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/cgi/rudailynews/getsnt.py", line 24, in <module>
    random.choice(words['word3']))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
[Fri Oct 30 20:42:30.165448 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 10959:tid 140680244426496] [client 127.0.0.1:40434] End of script output before headers: getsnt.py
```

I've tried solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860540/2778712) (second example) which only runs in python3, and browser is showing a blank page.

```
def set_output_encoding(codec, errors='strict'):
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(
        sys.stdout.detach(), errors=errors,
        line_buffering=sys.stdout.line_buffering)

set_output_encoding('utf8')
```

and in logs i have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/cgi/rudailynews/getsnt.py", line 21, in <module>
    words=json.loads(wordsfile.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can get *words.json* *[here](https://bitbucket.org/Sheogorath2/web/src/d89b43ed8912eee68f6b1ec245c42af0ecd004e9/html/words.json?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)*. I don't know which encoding it is i just downloaded it using *wget* (direct link [here](https://bitbucket.org/Sheogorath2/web/raw/d89b43ed8912eee68f6b1ec245c42af0ecd004e9/html/words.json)). How to make cgi make output in UTF8?

edit: I changed LANG in envvars to . /etc/default/locale, added PassEnv Lang to my vhost config and uncommented AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 in charset.conf, but *sys.stdout.encoding* is still ANSI_X3.4-1968 in browser and UTF-8 in console. Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print (sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322410/set-encoding-in-python-3-cgi-scripts

Comment: @Robᵩ switched to WSGI, everything works fine, buy thx anyway