# Python CGI Unable To Decode Degree Sign (°)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, character-encoding, cgi

I have an executable Python 3.6 CGI script that is running on an Apache2 server, Ubuntu 18.04.

When the script tries to execute this line:
`print("<p>Something about latitude x°</p>")`,
it throws the error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 203: ordinal
> not in range(128)

Even though the encoding is specified as UTF-8 in the HTML head with `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

When I try to force UTF-8 on the string with `.encode('utf-8')`, i.e.

`print("<p>Something about latitude x°</p>".encode('utf-8'))`,
the error disappears but  the degree sign shows up as UTF8 hex

> Something about latitude x\xc2\xb0

I tried setting an environment variable `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` in `/etc/environment` and created a global variable `/etc/profile.d/python-encoding.sh`, then reloaded both files using `source`, and restarted Apache2 server `systemctl restart apache2`, but to no avail.
CGI version: 2.6.

Comment: you should use [HTML entity](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) `&deg;` in place of `°` and browser will display  `°` in place of  `&deg;` - `"<p>Something about latitude x&deg;</p>"`

Comment: @furas thanks for the tip. This works only if the text was entered directly into the html, but in many cases the content is actually fetched from other servers so I need to solve the encoding issue in order to display the page correctly.

Comment: how about `text.replace('°', '&deg;')` ? Strange is that you can use `html.unescape('&deg;')` to get `°` but `html.escape('°')` doesn't give `&deg;`. I found only `'°'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`

Comment: See also [Python CGI - UTF-8 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860034/python-cgi-utf-8-doesnt-work).

Comment: @furas declaring the default charset and setting the environment variable for Python encoding in Apache2 .conf did the trick. Thanks man.

Comment: you can mark your answer as accepted and later upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the default charset and setting the environment variable for Python encoding in Apache2 .conf did the trick, as mentioned here: [Python CGI - UTF-8 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494458/13378545)

As pointed out by @furas.